# Why do I always get a permission issue when trying to install python packages?

Tags: macos, pip, homebrew

Whenever I try to install packages through homebrew or pip, it gives me a permission error. (I'm using macOS Catalina)

I somewhat got pip to work by using the "sudo -H" prefix. It downloads them successfully but then when I attempt to import them in Python, it tells me the module wasn't found. Earlier today I changed the default version of Python to 3.8.2, but the same error was happening way before that.

Here's the Homebrew command I used:

```
brew install libyaml
```

Here's what it's returning:

```
Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server/node_modules/term-size/vendor/macos/.DS_Store
```

Comment: Try running `brew doctor` from Terminal. Chances are you have permissions set up inconsistently, possibly do to a mix of `sudo` and non-`sudo` commands to install things.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check user permissions on the first `/usr`, `/usr/local`, and `/usr/local/lib` directories. you need `rwx` permissions to write content in these folder. Failing this permission on any folder will not allow you to modify content in `/usr/local/lib`.

you can use `sudo chmod u+rwx folder_name` to provide read write execute on the folders. If you want to provide`rwx` permission to all folder inside `/usr` use `sudo chmod u+rwx -R /usr`